# Cocoa osx: Is it a good idea to make an NSViewController and use it's view for the main window contentview?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nswindow

I have an `NSWindow` that I display for my Mac App called `window`. I display my ViewController's view inside the window with the following code.

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc]init];
self.window.contentView = viewController.view;
[self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

However, I am not sure if this is the best way to go. I've seen similar code on the internet, but I am now suspicious about it. I don't think it is best practice, but I could be wrong.

Should I just use an `NSView` instead of an `NSViewController`?

Any tips or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: It does work, but I don't think it is best practice.

Comment: Having one window controller and one main content view controller that has child view controllers is a good practice. Requires bit more code but one doesn't end up with MVC (massive view controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View controllers are the modern way (innovated from iOS) and you should use them. But that is not how. You cannot just arbitrarily create a view controller and steal its view and stuff it into the interface. The view controller itself serves no purpose in the code you showed.